# .NET Core 2.0 Correct way to route from area to nonarea

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a .NET Core 2.0 MVC app structured with an area called admin.

- Areas

  - Admin

    - Views

      - Home

        - Index.cshtml
    - Controllers

      - HomeController.cs
- Controllers

  - HomeController.cs
  - ManageController.cs
- Views

  - Home

    - Index.cshtml
  - Manage

    - Index.cshtml

I would like to have routes in _Layout.cshtml such as /controllers/manage/index that will work both when not in an area and when in an area such as admin.  Using either HtmlHelper syntax or TagHelper Syntax how can I create this?

Desired output:

> www.website.com/manage

I have tried

```
<a asp-area="" asp-controller="Manage" asp-action="Index" title="Manage">Manage</a>
```

Which works when not in an area, but when in the admin area produces a link to:

> www.website.com/admin

I have the following routes registered in Startup Configure(IapplicationBuilder app)

```
// Route for areas
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "areas",
        template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
    );
});

// Default route
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas), you have it correct. Best guess is that you haven't registered the area route.

Comment: What are you expecting it to generate?

Comment: @StephenMuecke updated the question to include desired output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are registering MVC twice.

```
// Route for areas
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "areas",
        template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
    );
});

// Default route
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

In this case, the *last registration* overwrites the first one, so you in effect only have 1 route registered (and no route for areas).

To fix this, you need to register MVC only one time and put all of the routes in that instance.

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    // Route for areas
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "areas",
        template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
    );

    // Default route
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```